# SQL querying multiple tables in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm currently trying to create a query so that I can output the full details of a band stored within my database. There are currently 5 tables in my database, they are, `bands`, `gigs`, `members`, `comments` and `tracks`. What I want to do is link all the data from each of the tables to the corresponding band provided in the URL variable. For example:

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="get-details">
    Select *
    From bands, gigs, members, comments, tracks
    Where gig_bandid = URL.id and member_bandid = URL.id and comments_bandid = URL.id and track_bandid = URL.id
</cfquery>
```

I wanted to do this because currently, I have 4 separate queries checking each of the four tables to see if they have any data contained matching the band id of the one provided in the URL. The issue I have is I want to output it all in one query, using terms such as `member_name`, rather than having to use `get-members.member_name`. I've tried using `JOIN` but to no avail. I assume that only works using two tables. Can provide extra details if needed.

Comment: The structure of the tables would probably be good to have.

Comment: What do you mean by the structure of the tables?

Comment: I meant the structure of the tables, primarily: what columns they have, data types for those columns, primary and foreign keys to indicate how the tables relate to each other.

Comment: you can chain JOINs together, so you can join more than 2 tables. What happens if you type your query in a sql client?

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by SQL client, i'm still quite new to this. I can write basic queries that select data based on an input, insert new data, delete data and update data. That's probably as far as my knowledge with SQL goes. And the structure I mainly tend to use nvarchar for fields containing alphanumeric characters but for the unique id fields such as band_id, member_id etc. i use int and make it the unique identifier.

Comment: The "*SQL client*" is the application where you type your SQL statements. Also which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: see the answer below by sgeddes. Is it possible that one or more of the tables does not contain data for the band ID? if so, then nothing is returned for that id with your query. What DB are you using? A SQL client is a program that allows you to execute a query and see the result immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most certainly can use JOINs -- you may need OUTER JOINs if the data is in one table and not in the other though.

```
SELECT *
FROM bands b
   JOIN gigs g on b.bandid = g.bandid
   JOIN members m on b.bandid = m.bandid
   JOIN comments c on b.bandid = c.bandid
   JOIN tracks t on b.bandid = t.bandid
WHERE b.bandid = URL.id
```

Or you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN if you know the data is in your bands table but potentially not in your other tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM bands b
   LEFT JOIN gigs g on b.bandid = g.bandid
   LEFT JOIN members m on b.bandid = m.bandid
   LEFT JOIN comments c on b.bandid = c.bandid
   LEFT JOIN tracks t on b.bandid = t.bandid
WHERE b.bandid = URL.id
```

Comment: I think that the OUTER JOIN is probably the key to success here.

Comment: I think the second is probably best, as if they have clicked on a link for the band the band will always be present, but data such as members or tracks may not be if they decided not to add that data. Thanks for this. Marked correct.

Comment: @LeeB -- np, glad we could help.

Comment: Been frying my brain for days, end up with so many unnecessary extra queries when i could just combine them into one.

Comment: Can i just quickly ask, what is the purpose of the abbreviated letters for each of the tables?

Comment: It saves typing and makes the query shorter so it is more readable. You are giving each table an alias name.

Comment: @LeeB -- it's just an alias for the table name -- makes it easier than to type them out multiple times...

Comment: Ah i see! So say rather than putting getdetails.member_name i could use an alias of gd and use gd.member_name?

Comment: @LeeB -- that's a little different (that's your CF code).  This is just aliasing the table in the SQL.  Your CF would not change.

Comment: OK no worries, yeah i see what you mean because it's part of the cfquery tag, my bad! But that will come in handy when writing out queries in future. I just tried the left join method and it's worked 100% how i wanted it to. Thanks again, think i need a studying session on SQL soon.

Comment: @LeeB Beware data duplication if you chose this route. If a band has 4 members, and they had 8 gigs, you gonna have 32 rows to show. If there were 7 comments, you will see 224 rows, etc.

Comment: Ah, that will be an issue then. What i want it to do is display the one band, but all their gigs, members, tracks and perform all this within one query. Is that probably not possible to do? Or would it take a query of queries?

Comment: @LeeB -- didn't realize that was the case.  you might be best off using the multiple queries -- if not, you'll have to add logic in your CF to filter accordingly.  Best of luck.

Comment: @sgeddes Ah damn, but I have learnt about using join in queries and aliases so that has come in rather handy!

Answer (score 1):

I think you went in a right direction with JOIN statement.

However to join 5 tables at once you must provide some matching criteria so that you will be able to "join" all of those tables.

The statement will be similar to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM bands    AS b
    JOIN gigs     AS g ON g.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN members  AS m ON m.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN comments AS c ON c.bandid = b.bandid
    JOIN tracks   AS t ON t.bandid = b.bandid
WHERE b.bandid = URL.id
```

And the criteria for joining is **bandid** that appears in all 5 tables (and is the URL.id).

As mentioned in answer above you can use INNER and OUTER versions of JOIN.
Here is an article that explains the difference: http://www.wellho.net/mouth/158_MySQL-LEFT-JOIN-and-RIGHT-JOIN-INNER-JOIN-and-OUTER-JOIN.html

Comment: Your answer is correct however someone else beat you to it so i've marked their answer as correct. Thanks though.

Comment: Yes it did! Basically, if i put `members` left join `bands` every band will show up, but only the members which match up to bands will display and if i did right join, all the members would display but not all the bands, even if there wasn't a match present.